# rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled

Tags: node.js, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am running 3 docker containers, let's say:

1. container-1 (node.js application)
2. container-2 (Golang application)
3. container-3 (Golang application)

All these containers communicate using gRPC.

I am doing a unary RPC (Request/Reply) call in container-1 which calls a method of container-2. This method performs various operations and calls numerous unary RPCs (~20) of container-3.

During the whole process sometimes I get the following error (note: not every time, even my input  data is same):

`rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

And whenever the error comes, it occurs at one of the last 4-5 RPCs calls (in container-2).

**One thing I observed that this error comes after ~1 min from when I started the process.**

So,

1. There might be some default context time after the context gets canceled. If it is, how can I increase that time?
2. Can anyone please explain to me if there is something I am missing in the **context** or **gRPC** in Golang.

Thank you.

**Edit:**

Following is the gist code that shows how I am connecting and calling the RPC:

```
// load proto
const proto = await grpc.load(PROTO_PATH);

// connect to service
const SERVICE = new proto.types.MyService(SERVICE_ADDR, grpc.credentials.createInsecure(), {
    "grpc.keepalive_time_ms"             : (5 * 60 * 1000),
    "grpc.keepalive_permit_without_calls": 1,
})

// calling RPC
SERVICE.sync({
    id:     Id,
}, (err, resp) => {
    if (err) {
        return reject(err);
    }

    if (!resp.success) {
        return reject(new Error(`Action error: ${resp.intended_action}: ${resp.reason}`));
    }

    resolve(resp.intended_action);
});
```

Comment: after the change, did you receive the error after 1 minute? It looks like the call to the container2 creates a context with 1 min time and holds it until receive all responses from container-3 or the 1 mim passes.

Comment: yes, Even 2 mins deadline did the magic. But in my case, there was an Nginx configuration (which I missed initially) where also I have to change the `timeout` value (which was set to 60 secs).

Comment: A complete stack trace would help to identify if the canceled context is related to one of the calls being executed or to the call being handled, and hopefully give more clues.